# Spring Boot: how to inject dependencies into a class called by a library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-kinesis

I'm using Kinesis Client Library (KCL) and Spring boot. To use KCL, I have to implement a class (I named it `RecordProcessor`) for interface `IRecordProcessor`. And KCL will call this class and process records from kinesis. But when I tried to use dependency injection, I found it was not succeeded.

Here's the snippet for `RecordProcessor`:

```
@Component
public class RecordProcessor implements IRecordProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private SingleRecordProcessor singleRecordProcessor;

    @Override
    public void initialize(String shardId) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I use `Class SingleRecordProcessor` to process single each record from kinesis. And this is my `SingleRecordProcessor` class snippet:

```
@Component
public class SingleRecordProcessor {

    private Parser parser;

    private Map<String, Table> tables;

    public SingleRecordProcessor() {
    }

    @Autowired
    private void setParser(Parser parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    }
    @Autowired
    private void setTables(Map<String, Table> tables) {
        this.tables = tables;
    }

    public void process(String record) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to let spring framework automatically inject the `SingleRecordProcessor` instance into the class and use it. But I found that the field `singleRecordProcessor` is null.

Any idea why the dependency injection is failed? Or is it impossible to inject dependencies into a class which is called by other framework (in this case it's KCL)? Any suggestions will be appreciated! Really need some help please!!

[**UPDATE**]:

Sorry for not expressing the error clearly. The error was `NullPointerException`. I tried to inject `singleRecordProcessor` and call method `process()` on it. I think the injection was not successful so the instance `singleRecordProcessor` is null and there comes the NullPointerException.

More information is as follows:

I have a major class called `Application`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter("./app.pid"));
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = application.run(args);
    }
}
```

And I have the `MainProcessor` class which will call KCL.

```
@Service
public final class MainProcessor {
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public static void startConsumer() throws Exception {
        init();
        IRecordProcessorFactory recordProcessorFactory = new RecordProcessorFactory();
        Worker worker = new Worker(recordProcessorFactory, kinesisClientLibConfiguration);
        ...
        worker.run(); // this line will call KCL library and eventually call ProcessorRecord class.
    }
}
```

[**UPDATE2**]

`RecordProcessorFactory` only has one method like this

```
@Component
public class RecordProcessorFactory implements IRecordProcessorFactory {
    @Autowired
    RecordProcessor recordProcessor;
    @Override
    public IRecordProcessor createProcessor() {
        return recordProcessor;
    }
}
```

It creates a new `RecordProcessor` instance for KCL to use it.

Comment: What error (stacktrace) are you getting?

Comment: @PinkieSwirl I got null pointer exception. The instance singleRecordProcessor is null and I tried calling process() method on this instance

Comment: Did you enable component scanning? Since a nullpointer means no injection happened. If injection fails you normally get a different error during initialization. And can you add all relevant info to the actual question, not just the comment?

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Thanks for reply! I've updated the question. Yeah I think injection doesn't happen but don't know why. I used `@SpringBootApplication` so I think the component scanning is enabled.

Comment: What's that RecordProcessorFactory you have there?  It's not Spring's and if it is used to create RecordProcessors, they won't be Spring beans, and so Spring won't initialize them...  If you have to have it, look up how to create that factory as a Spring bean, with a @Lookup method that creates RecordProcessors - then both the factory and the processors will be Spring beans, and it should work like you meant it to...

Comment: @moilejter There's only one method in RecordProcessoryFactory which simply returns a new RecordProcessor. I've updated the question. Thanks for pointing out! So does that mean I also need to add @Component to RecordProcessorFactory? Could you please explain a little bit more on the `@Lookup` method? Thanks!!

Comment: You don't want to do a `new RecordProcessorFactory` - just autowiring a RecordProcessorFactory in your MainProcessor instead, then passing that in to the Worker constructor may be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should autowire an instance of this into your MainProcessor:

```
@Component
public class RecordProcessorFactory {
    @Lookup IRecordProcessor createProcessor() { return null; }
}
```

Spring will instantiate a RecordProcessorFactory for you, and replace the implementation of createProcessor() in it with one that will return a new IRecordProcessor each time it's called.  Both the factory and the processors will be Spring beans - which is what you want.

Comment: Oh right! I shouldn't directly use `new` to create `RecordFactory.` Thanks!